Weak convergence in $L^2$ and uniform boundedness in Bochner space implies weak limit in Bochner space
Assume $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open bounded, and $U_T = (0,T) \times U$.
Given a sequence $(u_m)$ in $L^2(U_T) \cap L^\infty\left((0,T);L^2(U)\right)$ such that
$$u_m \rightharpoonup u \text{ in } L^2(U_T),$$
and
$$\|u_m\|_{L^\infty\left((0,T);L^2(U)\right)} \leqslant K.$$
How can I show that $u \in L^\infty\left((0,T);L^2(U)\right)$?
—
I have tried the following: First noting that
$$u_m \rightharpoonup u \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \int_{U_T} u_m v \to \int_{U_T} uv,$$
for any $L^2$-measurable $v$, and
$$\begin{align}
\left\vert \int_{U_T} u_m v \ \right\vert \leqslant \int_{U_T} |u_m v| &= \int_{0}^{T} \int_{U} |u_m v| \\ &\leqslant \int_0^T \|u_m\|_{L^2(U)}\|v\|_{L^2(U)} \\ &\leqslant K \int_0^T \|v\|_{L^2(U_T)} \\ &\leqslant K T^{1/2} \|v\|_{L^2(U_T)}\end{align},$$
where the second and last inequalities used Cauchy-Schwarz.
I suppose this says
$$\left\vert \int_{U_T} uv \ \right\vert \leqslant K T^{1/2} \|v\|_{L^2(U_T)}.$$
I wanted to replace $v$ by $u$, then this would imply
$$\|u\|_{L^2(U_T)} \leqslant K T^{1/2}.$$
But I'm not sure how to introduce the norm in $L^\infty\left((0,T);L^2(U)\right)$ from here to show that it's bounded. It might be that this direction is entirely wrong

One possibility is to show that the set of functions satisfying that $L^\infty$-norm constraint is closed wrt to $L^2(U_T)$ norm (and convex) hence weakly closed.

By modifying each function $u_m$ on a set of measure zero in $(0,T)$, you can assume that the essential supremum is a supremum, so that
$$\|u_m(t)\|_{L^2(U)}\le K$$ for all $t\in (0,T)$ and all $m$.  Given $v\in L^2(U)$ with $L^2$ norm less than or equal to $1$, consider the function $w(x,t)=\chi_E(t)v(x)$.  By weak convergence, Holder’s inequality in the $x$ variable and the previous inequality, $$\int_E\int_Uu(x,t) v(x)\,dxdt\le m_1(E)K.$$ Since this inequality is true for all measurable sets $E$ in $(0,T)$, by this it implies that
$$\int_Uu(x,t) v(x)\,dx\le K$$
for a.e. $t$. The set of measure zero depends on $v$. Now consider a dense set $v_k$ in the closed unit ball of $L^2(U)$. Then
$$\sup_k\int_Uu(x,t) v_k(x)\,dx\le K$$ for a.e, $t$.
Since by Fubini’s theorem $u(\cdot,t)\in L^2(U)$ for a.e. $t$, for any good $t$ the previous inequality implies $$\|u(t)\|_{L^2(U)}\le K$$
by sup.

Thank you very much for your answer! Most of this makes sense, but I wanted to ask why one would need to "consider a dense set $v_k$ in the closed unit ball of $L^2(U)$". Would it also work to simply choose $v(x) = \frac{u(\cdot, t)}{|u(\cdot, t)|}$, then we'd get the result without having to invoke sup?

$v$ cannot depend on $t$. We need a countable set because countable unions of sets of measure zero have measure zero, but this is not true for uncountable

Using @daw's suggestion, we can also make use of the fact that strongly closed + convex $\Rightarrow$ weakly closed. So if we show that $B := \{v \in L^2(U) : \|v\|_{L^\infty\left((0,T),L^2(U)\right)} \leqslant K\}$, then $u_m \rightharpoonup u$ with $u_m \in B$ would imply $u \in B \subset L^\infty\left((0,T),L^2(U)\right)$.
Convex: by triangle inequality.
Strongly closed:

Note the fact that if $f_n \to f$ in $L^2$, then there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ which is pointwise convergent almost everywhere.
If $v_m \to v$ in $L^2(U_T)$, then by Fubini have $$\int_0^T\int_U v(t,x)^2 dx dt = \lim_{m \to \infty} \int_0^T\int_U v_m(t,x)^2 dx dt.$$ Thus $\|v_m(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(U)} \to \|v(t, \cdot)\|_{L^2(U)}$ in $L^2((0,T))$, and by 1 we get $$\|v_m(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(U)} \to \|v(t, \cdot)\|_{L^2(U)}$$ pointwise for a.e. $t$.
For each $m$, $\|v_m(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(U)} \leqslant K$ for a.e. $t$. Since union of countably many null sets is null, and using 2, $$\|v(t,\cdot)\|_{L^2(U)} \leqslant K$$ for a.e. $t$ as well. Therefore $v \in B$, and $B$ is strongly closed, as desired.

